# Why am I getting unexpected results with pack('H*', ...) with perl 5.12.4 and 5.20.2?

Tags: perl, pack

I'm XORing, `($a ^= $b)`, strings and must express them as hex numbers. I can do this with `sprintf` but I prefer using `pack('H*', ...)`, if possible. I've packaged test code that expresses the problem with embedded comments. Can anyone explain why the `pack('H*', ...)` statement is failing? Thanks and regards.

```
use strict;

my @a = qw(a b c d e f g h);
print "@a\n";
my @b = map ord, @a;
foreach (@b) { print "$_\n" };
print scalar(@b), "\n";
my $pad = pack('H*', @b);   # why doesn't this work????
print "\$pad after pack('H*', \@b) = $pad \t\t # garbage :-(\n";
print length($pad), "\n";
$pad = pack('C*', @b);
print "\$pad after pack('C*', \@b) = $pad \t # correct\n";

$pad =~ s/(.)/sprintf("%x",ord($1))/eg;
print "\$pad after sprintf() = $pad\t # correct :-)\n";

exit(0);
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Note: `foreach (@b) { print "$_\n" };` is better written as `print "$_\n" for @b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What result do you actually want?

The `H` template for `pack` expects a hex string and returns a string consisting of the characters at those hex code points. So `pack 'H*', '414243'` will give you `ABC`

At a guess you want the reverse of that, so use `unpack` like this

```
my @a = qw(a b c d e f g h);
say unpack 'H*', join '', @a;
```

**output**

```
6162636465666768
```

Comment: Thank you Borodin. Pilot error on my part. I assumed pack converted its LIST argument based on TEMPLATE. Now I can do what I really want which is the equivalent of $pad = 'abcdefgh'; $pad = unpack 'H*', $pad; and avoid using that inefficient s// expression.

Comment: @perlboy: Each template will generally use up one of the items in the list, so `pack '(H*)*', '414243', '444546'` gives you `ABCDEF` and ``pack '(H2)*', '414243', '444546'`` gives `AD`

Comment: yup, I get it now, thanks. Where $pad is an ASCII string I can do $pad = unpack 'H*', $pad; $msg ^= $pad; $msg = pack 'H*', $msg; to get readable ASCII. Works great and is faster than regex.